# Relationship between Bandwidth and FLOP rating?

Tags: parallel-processing

Consider a case of p processors hanging off a shared bus. The peak bus
bandwidth is 40GB/s. Each of the processors performs a computation that requires
access to 4 bytes for each floating point operation (FLOP). What is the
peak FLOPs rating of such a system? What is the number of processors, p, for
which this peak rate is achieved?

Found this problem on a Homework Set online.. I believe we need to assume a value for the Processor clock. Am I right? Or is the given information enough?

Comment: No, you are wrong.  The information given is enough to answer the question.  Ask yourself how many FLOPs a system such as you describe could process if each processor could run at infinite speed.

Comment: I solved it assuming that the processor is set at 1 GHz. (The question said make reasonable, well stated assumptions). And my answer was 40 GFLOPS at 10 processors.